# Let ()=log() where we don't know the base .

Tags: logarithms

Let ()=log() where we don't know the base .

However, we do know that
(2)=0.37031
and
(3)=0.58692

Use this information to compute

(4)=

(^2)=

(^3)=

(6^5)=

I tried to do 0.37031=log2 and 0.58692=log3 and convert both to exponential form but I'm not sure how to find the base  value. Any tips on how to properly start this question would be appreciated!

Comment: Thanks saulspatz!

Comment: Please review the properties of logarithms. Also the fact that $\log_a a=1$

Comment: A more general version of the equation which GReyes provided is $\log_a{a^n} = n$ for all $n$. You can use this solve $2$ of the values you are trying to compute.

Comment: And $\log_a mn = \log_a m + \log_a n$ will solve all the rest.

Comment: It would be very mean of me to actually answer your question.  But I am mean so I will.  If $\log_a 2 = 0.37031$ then $a^{0.37031} =2$ so $\ln a^{0.3701} = \ln 2$ so $0.3701 \ln a = \ln 2$ so $\ln a = \frac {\ln 2}{0.3701}$ so $a = e^{\frac {\ln 2}{0.3701}} = 2^{\frac 1{0.3701}} = 2^{\frac {10000}{3701}}$

Answer (score 1):

Just do it.

You know $\log_a b^m = m\log_a b$ so you can use this to solve $L(4) = \log_a 2^2$.

And you know $\log_a a^k = k$ which you can use to solve the next two.

And you know $\log_a bc = \log_a b + \log_a c$ which you can use to solve the last one.